# How do I store a value of a return statement from a function inside a loop without getting a TypeError?

Tags: python, function, variables, typeerror, computer-science

Im trying to make a program and I need to call the function which checks the difference every single time and I store it in a variable. Problem is I get a TypeError. What would be a solution to this problem?

Tried assigning the function to a variable that way it updates each time it is called.

Heres the code:

```
def difference(word):
    counter = 0
    difference = 0
    for letter in word_one:   
        if letter != word[counter]:
            difference += 1
        counter += 1
    return difference


global difference
global word
attempts = 0
word = ''

global word_one
global word_two
word_picker()


print("Turn this word: "+str(word_one))
print("Into this word: "+str(word_two))
print()


while word != word_two:
    word = input("Enter word: ")
    word = list(word)
    word_one = list(word_one)
    word_two = list(word_two)
    difference = difference(word)
    if difference > 1:
        print("You can only change one letter at a time!")
        print()
```

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Yep. Sorry forgot to add.

Comment: Please post the error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the name `difference` for your function but then assigning a value to the same name. By the second iteration `difference` contains an int rather than a function and throws a TypeError when called.

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know you need to have 2 different names